# javascript split with line or space

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to split this code

```
<h1>
                                   999 street
                                   <br>
                                   city
                                   , 
                                   AA
                                   
                                   90777
                                   <br>
      </h1>
```

So far I can get this:

```
const address = document.querySelector('h1')

let street = address.split(',')
let pre_postalCode = street[2]
```

So I can get the part after ,
But the following code doesn't work

```
let pre_postalCode2 = pre_postalCode.split(' ')
let postalCode = pre_postalCode2[1]
```

I can't get the "90777", it returns nothing
I tried something like

```
let pre_postalCode2 = pre_postalCode.replace(/\br/g, " ").split(" ")
```

It doesn't work

Comment: What is `address`?

Comment: It seems it's a newline (`\n`) rather than whitespace. So you can try splitting with `.split('\n')`

Comment: Note that `" ".split(" ")` return  `[ '', '' ]`

Comment: @Ram sorry it is  "const address = document.querySelector('h1')"

Answer (score 2):

With this regex, you can split the text by newline value. After this, you must have a pattern or you must know the order of the specific word/line that you want to get the value from. For example, if you know that the postal code will always be on the 8th line then you can do this.

```js
const data = `<h1>
                                   999 street
                                   <br>
                                   city
                                   , 
                                   AA
                                   
                                   90777
                                   <br>
      </h1>`;
let values = data.split(/\r?\n/).map(n => n.trim());
console.log(values[7]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
var arr = `<h1>
                                   999 street
                                   <br>
                                   city
                                   , 
                                   AA
                                   
                                   90777
                                   <br>
      </h1>`.split("\n").map(val => val.trim()).filter(val =>  val && val !== "<br>" && val !== ",");
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can identify just numbers from some parts of the string and work with them:

```js
const str = `<h1>
                                   999 street
                                   <br>
                                   city
                                   , 
                                   AA
                                   
                                   90777
                                   <br>
      </h1>`

matches = str.split(',')[1].match(/\d+/g);

matches.forEach(res => console.log(res));
```